# How to deal with the deleted items in a struct

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am using struct , as I have been asked to so in my assignment . I have deleted a particular struct item from an array , I want to assign a new element at the deleted location , how to achieve that .

```
const int IN_USE=5;

struct process
{
    int processID; // added by user4581301 to make sample compile
};

struct ReadyQueue
{
    int size;
    struct process * Active;   // Pointer to another struct
    struct process * readyProcesses[IN_USE]; // Array of pointers
} ready;


int main()
{
    ready.Active = new struct process; // just one object
    // Allocate one object for each index in the array
    for(int i=0;i<IN_USE;i++)
        ready.readyProcesses[i] = new struct process;
    // after assigning values to all the individual processes  

    delete ready.readyProcesses[1]; // delete the second  item
    ready.readyProcesses[1] = 0; 

    int readyCount=0;     

    while(readyCount<IN_USE)
    {
        if(ready.readyProcesses[readyCount]==0) // trying to check if it is deleted
        {
            ready.readyProcesses[readyCount] = new struct process;
            // when I try to set or print  member variable gives segmentation fault 
            ready.readyProcesses[readyCount]->processID=103;
         }
         readyCount++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above program if I want to assign an element at position 1 again . I get segmentation faults . How to address this issue .

Comment: Where is the code that seg faults?

Comment: can you complete your example so we have a example from which we can get the error?

Comment: Same way as you addressed the fact the array initially had 5 useless elements - you create one. As in, _exactly_ the same way - `readyProcesses[1] = new struct process;`

Comment: I have added the  code

Comment: Warning: It appears you are being taught C with classes, not C++.

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: @user4581301 - good catch. Ashamed to say I didn't catch the use of new. (pun unintended)

Comment: Likewise unable to reproduce. Valgrind reports your leaks, but that's it. These aren't the droids you're looking for.